# Export Bugzilla and reimport/move to new server?

Tags: bugzilla

I've created a new VM to host our outdated Bugzilla server and now I need to move the database over to the new VM.

Our old server is running Bugzilla 2.16.3, which I plan on using on the VM as well.  This is just to get it off the old hardware.  I don't want to mess with VM Converter for something like this.

So my question is:

1. How can I export/reimport the Bugzilla database and settings?
2. Anything else I need to setup, understand before I do this?

I'm not a Linux expert either, so forgive me.  I'll be using Fedora 9 to host Bugzilla with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Things you must take care of:

- Web server setup. Apache + mod_perl most likely.
- Exporting SQL dump and importing it to a new server.

export for mysql:

*mysqldump --force --opt --user=$USER --password=$PASSWORD --databases $db > bugzilla.sql*

import for mysql:

*mysql -u $USER -p < bugzilla.sql*

- Install missing PERL CPAN modules

Run ./checksetup.pl in bugzilla directory to get a report on what's missing. It'll also show you the lines needed for installation. If installing via perl directly fails (which often does), try using your local disto package manager to install missing stuff (yum on Fedora I take it?)

- Point your browser to the new installation and debug further issues.

Comment: +1 for the ./checksetup.pl script, wish I knew about that last time I tried to do this.  I recommend trying to get the Perl modules via a repository before CPAN as well unless you need the latest version of the module for some reason.

Comment: OK, when I try and import I get the following error:

ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 4:  You have an error in your SQL syntax.

Comment: You may need to hand tune the SQL dump to make it pass importion without errors. Could you edit the main question with additional info, showing what line cause it to error?